# How to install plugin while launch the chrome browser?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium,cucumber and java for automation testing.

I have a requirement of installing a plugin to the chrome browser to open my application. This plugin I have already installed. But when I open the chrome browser through selenium this plugin is missing and application is not working.

How to install the plugin each time when the browser is opening?

Comment: Did you try developer mode and using unpacked extension in chrome?

Comment: Do you have CRX  file in your machine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using **Chrome 65.0** and **Selenium 3.11.0**

**Steps :**

1. Run the following URL in Chrome:   chrome://version/
2. Copy the Chrome profile path.
3. Open the Chrome profile path in Windows Explorer.
4. Open the Extensions folder (See the date and timestamp, when you installed that extensions)
5. Copy the folder path.

**Code :**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
            String pathToExtension = "C:\\Users\\USER_DELL_2014_07\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 3\\Extensions\\bhlhnicpbhignbdhedgjhgdocnmhomnp\\2.0_0";
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("load-extension=" + pathToExtension);
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
          }
```

That's it! You can use this code and chrome would be instantiated with the given extension

Please let me know if you have any concerns related to this.

Comment: I cannot find the Extensions folder when open the Chrome profile path in Windows Explorer.I am using windows 7.

Comment: Add the extension manually, (remove the previously added extension and then add the same extension) , are you able to navigate to the chrome profile folder in windows explorer ?

Comment: Once you paste the chrome profile path in (Win+R), hit enter then search for Extensions folder

Comment: @cruisepandey How to add multiple extensions in a browser?

Comment: @ChandraShekhar :   use  options.addArguments(List<String> arugments ) instead of only options.addArguments(String). They are overloaded methods

Comment: I haven't tried multiple extensions in one shot , I will try and update you !