# Selenium Chromedriver not navigating to url

Tags: python, selenium

What I have now is:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension(r"C:\Users\x\OneDrive\Desktop\pp\crxSolver.crx")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\x\OneDrive\Desktop\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

I am able to open the webdriver and I see the extension that I added on the right top corner in google Chrome, however the driver doesn't go to google.com. I have searched a lot and I can't find the solution to it.

Here is the link to the extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/buster-captcha-solver-for/mpbjkejclgfgadiemmefgebjfooflfhl/related

[Watch the video here for complete information](https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/1y3V0g3a1E3x163A0n2N/Screen%20Recording%202019-05-18%20at%2012.45.51.25%20AM.mp4)

Comment: long ago, I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788590/how-to-install-plugin-while-launch-the-chrome-browser/49791640#49791640

Comment: @cruisepandey, I have done the same..

Comment: Nobody knows the solution?

Comment: Generally when this happens it means that your driver and browser version aren't matched. Get the newest driver and make sure Chrome is up-to-date and try again.

Comment: Did you got any error message? what's your selenium and chrome driver and chrome version?

Comment: @supputuri, no I don't get an error message. I have chrome version 74 and I am using chromedriver version 74. If I'm not using the chrome options, everything will work fine and the driver is going to google...

Comment: Ok, let me try with adding .crx and see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @supputuri, thanks.

Comment: I Just tried with custom extension developed by me without any issue. Will give a try with the one you mentioned in the post. Can you please share the link to the crx that you are trying to load.

Comment: @supputuri, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/buster-captcha-solver-for/mpbjkejclgfgadiemmefgebjfooflfhl/related

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try upgrading to chrome 75, your issue should resolve. Seems to be some issue with the machine and your browser compatibility.