# Selenium browser not loading python with extension

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem with loading the browser in selenium. I can run my driver.get() when I'm not using an extension. When I am using an extension it is freezing on the google chrome white screen and I NEED to press the refresh button on the top left corner in order to load the page that I want. The extension is also loaded in the google chrome right top corner and I dont get an error message. It isn't going to the page that I want. I have changed the url's also but nothing is changing. I have both chromedriver as google chrome version 74. Im closing all the google chrome tasks from taskmanager and run the program but still not working.

What I have:

```
options = Options()
options.add_extension(r"C:\Users\x\OneDrive\Desktop\crxSolver.crx")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\x\OneDrive\Desktop\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get("https://yahoo.com")
```

[Displaying what is happening](https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/1y3V0g3a1E3x163A0n2N/Screen%20Recording%202019-05-18%20at%2012.45.51.25%20AM.mp4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Chromedriver not navigating to url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56164489/selenium-chromedriver-not-navigating-to-url)

Comment: @supputuri, yes but then I didnt know that I need to press the refresh button. The problem is also not solved.

Comment: I opened a bounty for your previous question, so please ignore this question. Feel free to add the video to the other original post.

Comment: @supputuri, I will..