# How to send keys to web browser using selenium and VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote simple code to login into gmail using Excel VBA as :

```
 Sub testEdgeAuto()
Dim obj As New WebDriver
Dim i As Integer
obj.Start "chrome", ""

obj.Wait 3000
obj.FindElementById("form-username").SendKeys ("my mail")
obj.Wait 3000
obj.FindElementById("form-password").SendKeys ("my password")
obj.Wait 3000
obj.FindElementById("login-btn").Click
obj.Wait 2000

End Sub
```

This works fine. But every time a new browser opens, and the work history of the previous browser vanishes. Also, I have to login every time using the above send keys.

Alternately, I used the code as below:

```
Sub demo()

Dim obj As New WebDriver
Dim i As Integer
  Dim chromePath As String

  chromePath = """C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""


 obj.Wait 3000
    obj.FindElementById("form-username").SendKeys ("my mail")
    obj.Wait 3000
    obj.FindElementById("form-password").SendKeys ("my password")
    obj.Wait 3000
    obj.FindElementById("login-btn").Click
    obj.Wait 2000
    

End Sub
```

This opens the chrome, in which password and login are already saved. But I can't able  to send keys using this code .This code gives error as shown below:. How to send keys using this code. Thanks

[enter image description here] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U6kS.png)

Comment: Read the error carefully `It says that the broswer has not started successfully` - What is wrong with the first approach ?

Comment: With first approach  it opens the new browser every time. Actually  I am using opening  this extension: chrome-extension://dehlblnjjkkbapjemjbeafjhjpjoifii/index.html                                       I had to add extension every time by manually clicking on Add extension Pop Up. I want to add extension once, and don't want to  click manually every time on popup button

Comment: Yes there's a way to launch browser with add-ons extension using Selenium. You do not need to do that manually everytime

Comment: I have no clue of that. Can you help me in this regard

Comment: I had given this solution in Java.. would be easy to convert it in VBA - try and let me know - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788590/how-to-install-plugin-while-launch-the-chrome-browser/49791640#49791640

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a sample code I use in my scripts. Find the path of the extension you want chrome to open with. Should be similar to this - `"USER_Libin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile\\Extensions\\tracker\\1.9"`

Create a variable to define the path and then try the below patch:

```
Sub Demo_Test()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver

    With driver
        .AddArgument “–-load-extension=” + pathToExtension
```

Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: `Sub Demo_Test()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
  Dim chromePath As String
  chromePath = """C:\Users\BILAL SHAH\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\dehlblnjjkkbapjemjbeafjhjpjoifii"""
    With driver
        .AddArgument “– - Load - extension = ” + pathToExtension
End Sub`                                              After compiling this code in excel VBA I'm getting the error: Load Argument not optional