# Is there a way to save extensions in chrome using selenium so that I don't have to load an extension each time I start a new chrome window?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I'm using a remote desktop where the chrome history is deleted everytime T restart it. Hence I'm having to manually download and install extensions each time I restart it. Is there a way to save extensions or load extensions into chrome using selenium? Note: I don't have admin access so I can't access the chrome/extensions folder locally.

Comment: don't know about selenium, but probably can use `pyautogui`, it should be just as simple as just giving the coordinates where to click in the correct sequence and allow it to click there. first make something to record the sequence, then just follow the instructions generated by this code to tell the other code where to click

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'Make something to record the sequence'?

Comment: pyautogui is also able to give You mouse coordinates, so You could set it up so, that say when You press the right click it prints the current mouse position or sth like that, that way You will know where to click when running the automation, maybe I will write an answer later showing that, now You can take a look at the docs [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and also [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) since it may have some useful features too (not necessarily (to get info do: `import keyboard`, then `help(keyboard)`))

Comment: This question was regarding plugin installation, the solution was given by me in Java, probably you may wanna have a look once - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788590/how-to-install-plugin-while-launch-the-chrome-browser/49791640#49791640

Comment: Does these articles solves your problem? [Use Google chrome extension with selenium and python](https://intoli.com/blog/chrome-extensions-with-selenium/) and [Use extension with selenium and python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/using-extensions-with-selenium-and-python)

Comment: @cruisepandey OP is clearly asking for python.

Comment: @Kshitiz, I don't have admin access so I can't access the extensions folder locally. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: @cruisepandey also OP mentioned having no access to the folder

Comment: @Kshitiz : I know , that's why I have not given that as an answer. it's pretty plain and simple, if OP thinks it can resolve, I'd be happy to convert that script to python

Comment: @Matiiss : I don't think admin access is required for this instance

Comment: @cruisepandey ok, so why didn't You just convert it to python and give as an answer, maybe in this particular case the question You linked to explains in pseudocode what is happening but still could be unreadable to people not knowing java, therefore they maybe wouldn't understand it and couldn't tell You if it was what they were looking for, tho I don't know, **however, if You think that it will solve the issue, You should post it as an answer**

Comment: @Kshitiz, the link you sent requires me to give the extensions folder path in the python script. I DO NOT have the rights t access that folder.

Comment: I am not sure if it will work out for OP, but OP can try this after setting the background. `options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
pathToExtension = "C:\\Users\\USER_DELL_2014_07\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 3\\Extensions\\bhlhnicpbhignbdhedgjhgdocnmhomnp\\2.0_0";
options.add_argument("oad-extension=" + pathToExtension)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options )`

Comment: Okay! Fine then using `pyautogui` could be best!

Comment: @cruisepandey you didn't understand that, don't have access to folder mean?

Comment: @cruisepandey OP has clearly mentioned 3/4 times that access to internal folders is not available option.

Comment: @Kshitiz : Well there's a way to install chrome in  remote machine as well (without admin access ) and then launch it using webdriver binaries . I am not certain why OP can't access it tho ? anyway I don't want any arguments, you win .

Comment: Thank you everyone, I think pyautogui is my only option.

Comment: OP didn't mention that why, don't have access to the files but we to take in consideration as told do have access to files!

Comment: @SwetaRajan I think we can install extensions by going to chrome webstore and install it using selenium and use it? Or you to have your own extension that you want to load?

Comment: it is the latter. It is my own extension that I want to load.