# extension not loaded using selenium on chrome 91

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to load an extension (crx file) using selenium script on chrome-91.
using below snippet in capabilities passed to chrome :
(in selenium script using javascript)

```
"goog:chromeOptions":{ 
    "extensions":[
        require('fs').readFileSync('/home/lenovoe14/chrome-extensions/3.2.1_0.crx').toString('base64')
    ]
}
```

browser is opened by the selenium script successfully but that extension not being loaded, although when tried on any lower version of chrome like 86 or 89 it is working on those versions correctly.

Any once can help about this different behavior of chrome-91, is there any extra config required on chrome-91 to load an extension or any other changes in this latest version causing this behavior.

Comment: I would use options to laod the extension. tag your binding language as well

Comment: ok @cruisepandey, using java script for selenium script, also tried using `chromeOptions` but didn;t find any luck there too

```
        "chromeOptions":{ 
            "extensions":[
                require('fs').readFileSync('/home/lenovoe14/chrome-extensions/3.2.1_0.crx').toString('base64')
            ]
        } 
```

Comment: any other suggested workaround on that context ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788590/how-to-install-plugin-while-launch-the-chrome-browser/49791640#49791640

Comment: you can check the above answer, since I am not into Java script much, I am not sure about syntax, above solution is in Java

Comment: thanks @cruisepandey
tried those things, but not worked, checking on any other workaround